# Is it possible to refer to a 10th and subsequent replacement strings in Oracle's regexp_replace?

Tags: regex, oracle

In Oracle's [`regexp_replace`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm#SQLRF06302) function, there is a parameter `replace_string` in which you can specify backreferences `\1` to `\9`.

Is there a way to refer to backreferences after the 9th one? Oracle treats `\10` as `\1` followed by a literal `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, nine is the max.

> \n
>
> Backreference
>
> Matches the nth
>   preceding subexpression, that is,
>   whatever is grouped within
>   parentheses, where n is an integer
>   from 1 to 9.
>
> [--
>   http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1013](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1013)

Note that this is not an Oracle limitation. Many (most?) regex implementations' maximum is nine.

Comment: +1 for pointer oracle documentation, looks like this is still the same in 11gR2 as well

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1013

Comment: Re: not an Oracle limitation. While it's true that not many regex engines understand \10, a number understand $10 or ${10} (e.g. Java, Perl, PHP, .NET). I was wondering if there was such an alternative syntax in Oracle. It looks like there isn't.