# Select group > 10 in REGEXP_REPLACE in teradata

Tags: regex, teradata

I have a regex, where I have around 19 groups and I need to select every single one. However when i try to select a group > 10, it selects group one and add the number behind the 1.

My regex looks like this:

```
pattern ='GPU = (\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s\sHDD = (\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\d*)'
```

And i want to replace all of it with the one item of the group with this code:

```
regexp_replace(text,pattern,'\19') as GPU_19 //OUTPUT--> AB9
```

I am using Teradata format.

Comment: Then it writes \019

Comment: It seems that the regex library in Teradata only supports POSIX like placeholders in replacement, that is, groups from 1 to 9 only.

Comment: [related : is-it-possible-to-refer-to-a-10th-and-subsequent-replacement-strings-in-oracles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564981/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-a-10th-and-subsequent-replacement-strings-in-oracles)